# display last login date in the frontend

Tags: login, date-time

I am using this codes to add the column in the users listing page to show the last login by users. This codes are in my function file of my template:

```
function insert_last_login( $login ) {
global $user_id;
$user = get_userdatabylogin( $login );
update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ), the_time('Y-m-j') );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'insert_last_login' );
function add_last_login_column( $columns ) {
$columns['last_login'] = __( 'آخرين ورود', 'last_login' );
return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_last_login_column' );
function add_last_login_column_value( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );
if ( 'last_login' == $column_name && $user->last_login )
$value = jdate( 'Y/m/d g:ia', strtotime( $user->last_login ) );
return $value;
}
add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'add_last_login_column_value', 10, 3 );
```

this codes is ok and no problem with it.

1- I want to show the date of last login by user in the template and frontend page according this codes.

2- and i want to sorting the columns of user listing page in order to last login by user.

can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 1 user_meta field for each user.
2. Upon login, fire an action of 'wp_login' that will update the new user_meta field for the current logged in user.
3. (Optional) Before updating the user_meta field, make sure it hasn't been updated earlier today. This will help avoiding server abuse